# Create new SQL table on form submit IF TABLE NOT EXIST

Tags: php, sql, forms, mysql

I am new to php and SQL so this is probably an easy question but I could not find any good sources online.

I am trying to create a SQL table when someone submits a form and this is what I have so far

```
  include("dbstufflive.php");     
  $cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$passwd,$dbname)
             or die("Couldn't connect to server");
     $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$company` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  ... (long list of table data)
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ";
    mysqli_query($cxn,$sql);
```

I will of course be doing other stuff with this table but I think I have most of that under control.

The problem is that this statement does not actually create my table :( The SQL statement works in phpadmin when I enter it as is and also there are no errors when the script runs. So it goes through all of this, and more, and seems to work but the table simply doesn't appear.

I can supply more code if needed but I don't want to paste more code here than is necessary.

Thanks in advance for any help from the community.

EDIT:
I was using wrong DBinfo...wow, I am not very bright.

Comment: Are you getting an error when you run in browser? Where are your login credentials stored? From the code you provided, it doesn't show your $host, $user etc being declared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL Statement looks fine - from the looks of it, you are missing your login credentials. An efficient way to do so:

```
// Add this line
require_once('config.php');

// Then change the variables below to pull your credentials from that file.
$cxn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD)
             or die("Couldn't connect to server");
     $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$company` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  ... (long list of table data)
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ";
    mysqli_query($cxn,$sql);
```

Then create a new file called config.php in same directory. Put your credentials:

```
<?php
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER', 'username');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'your_password');
    define('DB_DATABASE', 'database_name');
?>
```

Comment: I have all of that already, I just didn't want to post it, but thank you. I will edit my post so that is more obvious

Comment: OK, I am an idiot. I forgot I have 2 different databases (Live and Local) and I was using the wrong one.../wrist.

Comment: @james: haha it happens. glad you got it fixed

Answer (score 0):

You should check the result of mysqli_query (as far as i know it returns false on failure). See [mysqli documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for details, where you can read, that "Create table doesn't return a resultset" but True/false on sucess/failure.

example:

```
if (!mysqli->query($cxn,$sql)) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($cxn));
}
```

Comment: I did that and I get a return of "1" which I think is true.

Comment: If it worked, you should find your table. If not, you may not using the databse connection you thought you were using.